# No resource found that matches the given name Android

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-imageview, android-image

I just started learning android and i came across a strange error which i am not able to fix. I am using a image in image view but i get the error

**No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/st').**

I can see the image in the preview of Android Studio. I have st in the drawable folder.

[image]

And here is my xml

[image]

The weird thing is that if i change from st.png to bg.jpg it works. I am using android Studio. I am really confused any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Clean And Rebuild project

Comment: I did that but i get this error when rebuilding

Comment: try to restart the android studio

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the bug.I think my image file was corrupted! I switched the image and it worked. Thank you guys for helping out. Sorry to waste your time. Thanks